# React JS Login and Router are not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create login functionality in Reactjs, where I want user to be redirected to health page if he/she haven't signed in.

Login.jsx

```
import './Login.css';

import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const Login = (props) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState();
  // state = {
  //   email: '',
  //   pwd: '',
  // };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.isLogIn(true);
  };

  Login.propTypes = {
    isLogIn: PropTypes.boolean,
  };

  // function validateForm() {
  //   return email.length > 0 && pwd.length > 0;
  // }
  return (
    <div className="div-login">
      {/* <div className="div-login-logo">
          <Logo />
        </div> */}
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            placeholder="email..."
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            value={pwd}
            placeholder="password..."
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              history.push('/health');
            }}
          >
            Log In
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Here is **App.js** where I have written the logic using Redirect, however I am not getting the right results.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Health from './components/Health/Health';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound/NotFound';
import SidebarNav from './components/SidebarNav/SidebarNav';
import UserAdmin from './components/UserAdmin/UserAdmin';

const App = () => {
  const [hideMenu, setHideMenu] = useState(false);
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setHideMenu(window.location.pathname === '/');
  }, [window.location.pathname]);

  const handleLogin = (isLog) => {
    setState({ isLog });
  };
  let isLog = state;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        {hideMenu && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <SidebarNav />
            <Header />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        <div className={hideMenu ? '' : 'content'}>
          <main>
            <Switch>
            
              {
                <Route exact path="/">
                  {!isLog ? (
                    <Redirect to="/login  " />
                  ) : (
                    <Login isLogIn={handleLogin} />
                  )}
                </Route>
              }
              {/* <Route path="/" exact component={Login} /> */}
              {/* <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} /> */}
              <Route path="/health" exact component={Health} />
              <Route path="/useradmin" exact component={UserAdmin} />
              <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Expectation
As the user opens the url firstly he/she should see the login page, if the user is logged in he/she should be redirected to the /health page.

As I am new to Reactjs, Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Found this in your code:

```
const handleLogin = (isLog) => {
    setState({ isLog });
  };
let isLog = state;
```

See that you update state to be object with `isLog` property, while when you use it you expect it to be a primitive boolean.
after `setState({isLog})`, assuming isLog is false, you got `state = {isLog: false}`.
then the variavle `let isLog = state;` is actually not a boolean, but an object, which is a truthy variable whatever properties its have.
so when you check for `if(isLog)` you will always get true.

Change  `setState({ isLog });` to `setState(isLog);`

**2.** I not get the login of the following check:

```
{!isLog ? (
    <Redirect to="/login  " />
     ) : (
    <Login isLogIn={handleLogin} />
)}
```

**What its currently do is:**
If user not logged in, redirect from homepage to login page (while you commented out the login route), if he logged in, display login page in homepage route.

**What I guess you want to happen is:**
If user not logged in, redirect from homepage route to login route, and render login page on login route, if he does logged in, redirect from homepage route to health route, and render health page in health route.

The above suppose to looks like this:

```
<Switch>
            
              {
                <Route exact path="/">
                  {!isLog ? (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                  ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/health"/>
                  )}
                </Route>
              }
              <Route path="/login" exact  ><Login isLogIn={handle login}/>
              <Route path="/health" exact component={Health} />
              <Route path="/useradmin" exact component={UserAdmin} />
              <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
```

Comment: Thy @yosef, Thanks for you response but what about the handleLogin function where will I be using that in the code?

Comment: Just pass it to login page component, as you currently do. Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Yosef. Use State variable for boolean comparison instead of storing it in a variable.

I will suggest you should create a separate component for Private Routes. When user is logged in it ternary operator will go into Private Routes component. and if user is not logged in then ternary operator will show login page.

Even if you try to redirect to health page from URL. it will not move into Private Routes component. I did a small Route Protected Example for you.
Take a look at it.

Also you should checkout the documentation of React Router.

here is good article about protected routes
https://ui.dev/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Working Example:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
export default function BasicExample() {
  const [login, setlogin] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button name="btn" onClick={() => setlogin(true)} > login </button>
      </div>
    <Router>
      <div>
          <Switch>
               <>
                  {!login ? (
                   <Route path="/">
                     <Redirect to="/login" />
                    </Route>
                  ) : (
                    <PrivateRoute />
                  )}
                  <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                 </>
         </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
              </>
  );
}
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
function Login() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
       const routes = [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: Home,
            },
           {
                path: '/dashboard',
                component: Dashboard,
            },
            {
                path: '/about',
                component: About,
            }]
  return (
    <>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
            {routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
                <Route exact path={path} component={component} />
            ))}
            <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </>
  )
}
```